# How to enable output colors on nodejs running as systemd service

Tags: node.js, colors, systemd

I have a websocket client that sends periodically some message to websocket server. If I run the client from the tty, console colors work fine and the message sent to WebSocket are colorized. But if I execute this same client as a systemd service. The colors desappears of message sent to server. I don’t need to log something in the client, I just need to send the messages to the server.

The problem:

```
import colors from 'colors'

const message = colors.bold(colors.red('some text' ));

websocket.send(message);
```

The expected result is:

```
Message: \00033b]33some text\00088b[34 (something in this format)
```

But when I use this client as systemd service, 'message' variable always is 'some text'. Doesn't matter if I used colors to generate the colors or not.

Have some method that makes the same of 'colors' library, but only to generate the string, or have some option on colors that do it?

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Set a environment variable with `TERM='xterm-256color` in your systemd unit file. But why force the client to use colors?

Comment: To send the complete log information from the client to the server preserving all information of the original log. Because I'm using the log function it self to send a websocket request.

Comment: About what log functionality are you talking about? Just send them as a json string e.g. `{"level": "error", "msg": "foo bar"}`

Comment: Yeah. Already did that. I've created a response class containing all the properties, but the message string has some elements that are colored with different colors and bolded in some parts. I want to do a really bypass of the log from client to server.